# Which waveform leads the other: A or B?

Tags: signal, delay, encoder, waveform

If you only look at the waveforms A and B below, can you determine which one leads or lags the other? 
One person argues that A leads B because the first rising edge of A occurs before the first rising edge of B.
Another person argues that B leads A because the first falling edge of B occurs before the first falling edge of A. 
Who is correct in this scenario?
[image]

(https://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/index.php/Rotary_Encoder)

Answer (score 1):

Both are actually correct, but in practical use that is not what is important for a quadrature encoder.  As long as one signal "leads" the other, the shaft is moving in one direction.  When the other signal "leads", the shaft is moving in the opposite direction.  One determines the position of the shaft by counting the signal pulses (either adding one for forward or positive motion, or subtracting one for backward or negative motion).

Answer (score 1):

The signal for A is 90° of phase before the signal of B.  But phase angles are only unique when discarding multiples of 360°, and moving one slot of distance along the coding disk is equivalent to moving 360° in the context of those signals.  And according to the sketch, the signal sources are placed a multiple of slots away from one another, and an imperfection like an obstructed slot would require numerous cycles to travel from one detector to the other.

In that context, it makes little sense to talk of "leading" and "trailing": you track the quadrature.  If A has a transition and ends up the same as B, you count +1, if it ends up different, you count -1.  If B has a transition and ends up different from A, you count +1, if it ends up the same, you count -1.  The total accumulation will tell you the respective rotary distance covered since the start of counting.  "Leading" or "trailing" is assigning a bit too much importance: you just follow the scheme and will end up with a value.  And if you have positioned your sensors such that at constant speed their transistions will alternate evenly, all you need to figure out which direction the sign of your angles will indicate.

Answer (score 0):

If the rotating wheel and fixed mask's slots/openings are the same all the way around, I don't think you can tell.

If the mask slots were of, say, constantly increasing width around the wheel, then you could because the pulses out of one sensor would always be wider than those from the other sensor.

You also tell if the slots spacing was not uniform around the wheel or the mask.